# Make back quotes to be evaluated when using cat > file.txt in bash

Tags: bash

I have seen something like behinds.

```
cat >/etc/swift/swift.conf <<EOF
[swift-hash]
# random unique strings that can never change (DO NOT LOSE)
swift_hash_path_prefix = `od -t x8 -N 8 -A n </dev/random`
swift_hash_path_suffix = `od -t x8 -N 8 -A n </dev/random`
EOF
```

It seems that it intends to get and write random value while using cat. I have tried 'ctrl+d'(I'm running under putty client) at where 'EOF' was wrote, but 'od' was't executed. It just write raw input `od -t x8 -N 8 -A n </dev/random`. How can I run those back quoted command?

Comment: Did you use the `<<EOF` notation? Because that's necessary for this to work. You shouldn't need to use Ctrl+D.

Comment: @ruakh <<EOF worked. What a simple solution.. just copy and paste was all i need to do.